# How do I get Bestseller Product with REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I'm developing an Angular frontend that uses Magento 2 REST API.
I want to get the list of my bestseller products but can't find a way to get this with the APIs.

How do I retrive this list?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By Default there doesn't look to be a bestsellers endpoint, you would need to create your own using the `Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers`

You can see more information on how to create a custom API [here](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/magento-2-custom-api/)

Answer (score 2):

Get the Bestseller Product with REST API follow below Filepath and create custom API to get Bestseller Products collection.

> Filepath: magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Bestseller',
    __DIR__
);
```

> Filepath: magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Bestseller" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

> Filepath: magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/etc/webapi.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<routes xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Webapi:etc/webapi.xsd">
    <route method="GET" url="/V1/bestseller">
        <service class="Vendor\Bestseller\Api\ProductSlidersManagementInterface" method="getBestseller"/>
        <resources>
            <resource ref="anonymous"/>
        </resources>
    </route>
</routes>
```

> Filepath: magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Vendor\Bestseller\Api\ProductSlidersManagementInterface" type="Vendor\Bestseller\Model\ProductSlidersManagement"/>
</config>
```

> Filepath:
> magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/Api/ProductSlidersManagementInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Bestseller\Api;

interface ProductSlidersManagementInterface
{
     /**
     * Get Bestseller Product Slider api
     * @param int $currentPage
     * @param int $pageSize
     * @return \Vendor\Bestseller\Api\Data\ProductSlidersInterface
     */
    public function getBestseller($currentPage = 1, $pageSize = 10);
}
```

> Filepath:
> magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/Api/Data/ProductSlidersInterface.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Bestseller\Api\Data;

/**
 * ProductSlidersInterface interface.
 * @api
 */
interface ProductSlidersInterface
{
    /**
    * @return \Vendor\Bestseller\Api\Data\ProductSlidersInterface[]
     */
    public function getBestsellerProduct();

    /**
     * @param string $bestsellerProduct
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setBestsellerProduct($bestsellerProduct);

    /**
    * @return \Vendor\Bestseller\Api\Data\FeaturedSlidersInterface[]
     */
    public function getProductCount();

    /**
     * @param string $productCount
     * @return $this
     */
    public function setProductCount($productCount);  
}
```

> Filepath:
> magento/app/code/Vendor/Bestseller/Model/ProductSlidersManagement.php

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Bestseller\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;

class ProductSlidersManagement implements \Vendor\Bestseller\Api\ProductSlidersManagementInterface
{
    const PAGINATION = 10;
    const CURRENTPAGE = 1;

    protected $dataObjectFactory;    
    protected $_collectionFactory;
    protected $storeManager;
    protected $productRepository;
    protected $storeManagerInterface;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\DataObjectFactory $dataObjectFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Report\Bestsellers\CollectionFactory $collectionFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManagerInterface
    ) {
        $this->dataObjectFactory = $dataObjectFactory;
        $this->_collectionFactory = $collectionFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
        $this->storeManagerInterface = $storeManagerInterface;
    }

    public function getBestseller($currentPage = 1, $pageSize = 10) 
    {
        $result = $this->dataObjectFactory->create();
        if($pageSize == 0) {
            $pageSize = self::PAGINATION;
        }
        if($currentPage == 0) {
            $currentPage = self::CURRENTPAGE;
        }

        $storeId = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
        $mediaUrl = $this->storeManagerInterface->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
        $bestSellerProdcutCollection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
        ->setModel('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
        ->setPeriod('month')
        ->setPageSize(
            $pageSize
        )->setCurPage(
            $currentPage
        ); //you can add period daily,yearly
        //->setPeriod('year');
        //->setPeriod('day');

        $productData = [];
        $i = 0;
        $productCount = count($bestSellerProdcutCollection);
        foreach ($bestSellerProdcutCollection as $value) {
            $productId = $value->getProductId();
            $product = $this->productRepository->getById($productId);

            $productData[$i]['product_id'] = $product->getEntityId();
            $productData[$i]['name'] = $product->getName();
            $productData[$i]['price'] = $product->getPrice();
            $productData[$i]['sku'] = $product->getSku();  
            $productData[$i]['image'] = ($product->getImage())?$mediaUrl.'catalog/product'.$product->getImage():'';
            $i++;   
        }
        $result->setData('bestseller_product', $productData);
        $result->setData('product_count', $productCount);
        return $result;
    }
    
}
```

> **API:** {baseurl}/V1/bestseller
>
> **Params:** currentPage:  1
> pageSize:     10
>
> **Method:** GET

Comment: I am getting this error Consumer is not authorized to access %resources, how to fix it, I used exactly all your codes. Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I created an extension that fetches best seller products via Rest API https://github.com/troublediehard/mma-customapi

Comment: NIce one, thank you Dmitri!

Comment: @LeonardoMinati feel free to upvote the answer if you like it.